# Vue.js - Reactivity of a select whose value is the selected object and not its id

Tags: vuejs2

I'm using `vue.js 2.3` and `element-ui`. I'm facing reactivity issues with a select dropdown whose value is the `item` picked.

#### Problems

The `select` is not automatically filled with the initial object `value`

#### Notices

If I change `:value="item"` to `:value="item.name"`

and `form: {option: {name:'blue', price: ''}}` to `form: {option:'blue'}`

It is working

#### Questions

Is there a way to make the `select dropdown` fully reactive when its value is **not** just a `string` or a `id` but rather the whole object that has been selected

https://jsfiddle.net/LeoCoco/aqduobop/

```
<

div style='margin-bottom:50px;'>
My form object : 
  {{form}}
</div>

  <el-button @click="autoFill">Auto fill</el-button>

  <el-select v-model="form.option" placeholder="Select">
    <el-option v-for="item in options" :key="item.name" :label="item.name" :value="item">
    </el-option>
  </el-select>
</div>


    var Main = {
    data() {
      const options = [
     {name: 'blue', price: '100$'},{name: 'red', price: '150$'},
      ]

      return {
        currentItem: 0,
        options,
        form: {
            option: {name:'', price: ''},
        },
         testForm: {
            option:{name:'red', price: '150$'}
        },
      }
    },
    methods: {
      autoFill() {
        this.form =  Object.assign({}, this.testForm); // -> Does not work
      }
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Are your options always hardcoded or do they come from somewhere?

Comment: By default, the `form` object should be empty. The options are retrieved after an `AJAX` call. `testForm` is also retrieved after an `AJAX` to prefill the dropdown with `autofill` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that when the selected value is an object, then `form.option` needs to be the *same* object in order for it to be selected in the select list.

For example if I change the fiddle code to *this*, I think it works the way you expect.

```
var Main = {
    data() {
      const options = {
        'color': [{name: 'blue', price: '100$'},{name: 'red', price: '150$'}],
        'engine': [{name: '300hp', price: '700$'},{name: '600hp', price: '2000$'}],
      }
      let currentCategory = 'color'

      return {
        currentCategory,
        currentItem: 0,
        options,
        form: {
            option: options[currentCategory][0]
        },
         testForm: {
            option:{name:'blue', price: '100$'}
        },
      }
    },
    methods: {
      autoFill() {
        this.form =  Object.assign({}, this.testForm); // -> Does not work
      }
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

Here is your fiddle [updated](https://jsfiddle.net/8mtbv7to/2/).

You said your values are coming from an ajax call. That means that when you set `form.option` you need to set it to one of the objects in `options[currentCategory]`.

Comment: If you click on `autofill` it does not work https://jsfiddle.net/LeoCoco/p8rusa82/. Imagine the options takes 10min to be retrieved. Is it possible to prefill the dropdown with a local object `testForm` without making any reference to the `options`

Comment: Instead of doing `options[0]` is it possible to do ` {name: 'blue', price: '100$'}`

Comment: The autofill doesn't work because it is a *different* object. Even if it has the same properties.

Comment: Do you mean there is no way to prefill the dropdown with a different object that have the same properties? Yet when I click on `autofill` the `form` object, the one linked to the `select` changes

Comment: @Leo You want to show options before you have options to select?

Comment: If I know beforehand the exact structure of the option I want to select, yes.  Maybe it is impossible ...